# JS indexOf() not giving result of inputted number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to see the indexOf() of an array of numbers for an inputted value.

For regular numbers in the array it is not working, but if the number in the array uses quotes (such as "3"), it somehow works.

Why is this not working for a regular number without quotes?

```
<p><input type="number" id="inNum"></p>
<button onclick="indexCheck()">Check</button>
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
var arr = [1, 2, "3", 4];

function indexCheck() {
    var x = document.getElementById("inNum").value;
    
    var ind = arr.indexOf(x);

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ind;
    };
</script>
```

In the above example, 1, 2, and 4 give a result of -1 (so they are not found in the array) but 3 give result of 2 (so it is found in the array at position 2).

Yet somehow a non-inputted number can be found and it works fine:

```
<button onclick="indexCheck()">Check</button>
<p id="result"></p>

<script>
var arr = [1, 2, "3", 4];

function indexCheck() {
    var x = 2;
    
    var ind = arr.indexOf(x);

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = ind;
    };
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your input "number" is actually a string. Here's documentation of the [`HTMLInputElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement) interface; note that the `value` property is of type `string`.

So that's why it can find the value `"3"` in your array, but not the number `3`. In order to convert it to a number, you can use the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number#function_syntax) global function:

```
var string = "3";
var number = Number(string); // will be 3
```